# Capistrano 3 deploy assets:precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, capistrano3, puma

So I'm following this tutorial on my VPS which is Debian 7:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma

After the deploy, the last message on terminal is:

```
bash: line 1: 30225 Aborted                 ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
rake stderr: Nothing written
```

On the app directory doesn't have the "current" dir, just (shared/repo/releases)
Seeing by this link, I need to do something that is not in the tutorial?

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.18'
gem 'haml-rails', '0.5.3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'bower-rails', '0.9.2'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'puma', '2.11.3'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'compass-rails', '2.0.4'
gem 'libv8', '3.16.14.9'

group :assets do
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 2.5.0'
end

group :development do
    gem 'capistrano',         '3.4.0'
    gem 'capistrano-rvm',     '0.1.2'
    gem 'capistrano-rails',   '1.1.3'
    gem 'capistrano-bundler', '1.1.4'
    gem 'capistrano3-puma',   '1.1.0'
end
```

Deploy.rb:

```
# Change these
server 'server', port: 66, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@bitbucket.org:user/project.git'
set :application,     'portfolio'
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, false  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

Comment: You probably have an error in your assets. Try to run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` in your localhost and see if it works

Comment: I just do this, and it worked normally :/

Comment: even if you set the `production` environment?? `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: nice! really had some errors and I fixed it, but I'm fall in other error when I try to deploy now, do you know this?

SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host ivar: bundle exit status: 7
bundle stdout: Could not find libv8-3.16.14.9 in any of the sources
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Comment: You can't install some gem, probably `therubyracer`, due to the lack of some dependencies. What I would do is accessing the server and executing manually `RAILS_ENV=production bundle install` and see what the exact error is. You can easily google that, as it is a quite common error.

Comment: Sorry davids, I'm goggling a lot but I didn't find something that fix it, I updated this issue with my gemfile, `therubyracer` is already there, so I can't run the `RAILS_ENV=production bundle install` because my deploy is don't making the current folder, I don't have the place to run this, I installed the gem on the server running gem install libv8 and therubyracer but didn't work to, can you take a look at this tutorial, maybe I need to do something that is not on the tutorial?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to install those gems manually?

Comment: running gem install manually on the server works fine, the problem are still in deploy, the same message:

**The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host ivar: Exception while executing on host ivar: bundle exit status: 7
bundle stdout: Could not find libv8-3.16.14.9 in any of the sources
bundle stderr: Nothing written**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82014/discussion-between-wtkd-and-davids).

Comment: @davids I have fixed It restarting everything from zero, prob had some wrong config, ty for your time/patience helping me!! this tip to run **RAILS_ENV=production command** really helps a lot, ty!!!!!

Comment: No worries @wtkd, Capistrano is sometimes a bit hard to set up, but once you make it work, everything goes smoothly :)